# Filter OUT matching documents in elasticsearch with aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to query statistics about documents in elasticsearch with the following query. The problem is that I'm trying to ignore documents with certain values for the field `logger`, but I can't figure out how. The query below selects all the right documents *into* the set, but it doesn't exclude documents with the undesirable values.

Any suggestions very welcome.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "terms": {
              "logger": [
                "experimentsplitsegmentlogger_errors",
                "ExperimentLogger"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "terms": {
          "logger": [
            "experimentsplitsegmentlogger_errors",
            "ExperimentLogger"
          ]
        }
      },
      "must": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "keys": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "terms": {
              "logger": [
                "experimentsplitsegmentlogger_errors",
                "ExperimentLogger"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "terms": {
        "field": "logger"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hostnames": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "hostname"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "pids": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "pid"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "time_stats": {
                  "stats": {
                    "field": "timestamp"
                  }
                },
                "count_stats": {
                  "stats": {
                    "field": "count"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: your filter and terms aggregations are on the same level, terms has to be one level nested in `aggs` of `filter`, and why do you have filters 3 times, one time should work if it is correctly executed.

Comment: @SumitKumar I have it three times because it doesn't work. I would appreciate it if you could post an answer with an example of what you mean, because I find your meaning obscure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you as I removed `filter` and `terms` from the same level of aggregation.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
          "not": {
            "terms": {
              "logger": [
                "experimentsplitsegmentlogger_errors",
                "ExperimentLogger"
              ]
            }
          }
      },
      "must": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "keys": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "logger"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this in a second. I was under the impression that the `not` filter was deprecated.

Comment: @Marcin Yes `not` is deprecated. you should use `bool` with `must_not`. you can replace that in query, both will give you same result.

Comment: This works great. I actually realised that a large part of my problem was that I was saving my changes to a different file from the one I was running off, so I'm not certain that my problem was real, but I am certain that this answer is real and works.

Comment: `"filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "terms": {
              "logger": [
                "experimentsplitsegmentlogger_errors",
                "ExperimentLogger"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "terms": {
        "field": "logger"
      }` this was the only wrong part in your query, keeping three filters would just slow down the process but will give you same result